# calculate original sequence length in padded embedding lookup of a sentence in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

`text_tensor` is a tensor in shape `[None,sequence_max_length,embedding_dim]` that contains embedding look-up of a batch of sequences. The sequences are padded using zeros. I need to obtain a list named `text_lengths` in shape `[None]` (None is the batch size) that contains the length of each sequence without paddings. I've tried a couple of scripts.

The nearest I've got is the code below:

```
 text_lens = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.math.not_equal(text_tensor, tf.as_tensor(numpy.zeros([embedding_dim]))), dtype=tf.int32), axis=-1)
```

But still calculates the lengths incorrectly. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Will the zeros only appear as part of the padding, or can they also be the result of your computations within the sequence's original length?

Comment: `But still calculates the lengths incorrectly.` What does it mean in practice? Do you have an example?

Comment: @‌Reti43 only the padding tensors are fully zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood this correctly, after the sequence's original length you get 0s of size `embedding_dim` for the remaining indices of the first axis.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# batch_size = 2, first sequence length = 1, second sequence length = 3
data = [[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]]

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    tensor = tf.constant(data, dtype=tf.int32)
    check = tf.reduce_all(tf.not_equal(tensor, 0), axis=-1)
    lengths = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(check, tf.int32), axis=-1)
    print(sess.run(lengths))
```

Output

```
[1 3]
```